# Find text color of button in swift4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, uicolor

I am working on app and I give UIButton text color from storyboard (Different for default and selected), I want both text color in a variable.
Anyone help me with this problem.

I have one solution for this problem " Take 'color code' of this color and give it to variable"

Anyone has any other short method for this problem.

Because if I use 'color code' then in future when I change color of button text then Then also work on that 'color code'.

Comment: check like this : if([button titleColorForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIColor blueColor]]){}

Comment: Thanx Dixit is work for  me "sender .titleColor(for: .normal)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `titleColor()` method of `UIButton`

`let color = btnOutletExample.titleColor(for: .normal)`   `or your desired state`

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
let titleColor: UIColor = yourButton.currentTitleColor
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pull the colour out of the element you configured in your storyboard, using the following code.

```
let btnTextColor = self.myBtnOutlet.titleLabel.titleColor(for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

At the end of viewDidLoad, you can add the following to capture the color information:

```
let defaultTextColor = myButton.titleColor(for: .normal)
let selectedTextColor = myButton.titleColor(for: .selected)
```